# How to update 2 tables in one page in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

Assuming there are 2 tables in one page. table 1 shows the list of all items and table 2 shows the list of all deleted items. whenever i click delete button the corresponding row from table 1 is moved to table 2.

I am not sure how to do all these in one page!

Comment: simply create 2 forms. 1st form for post and 2nd form for get.

Comment: sorry could you explain more. what should i use to delete a row from table1 and what is going to add that row to table 2?

Answer (score 0):

Once, you click delete, you send a request to the server, once you get the response, you run an animation where you remove row and put on another table, this can be done by giving an id to your tr and then remove id and adding to the top of the 2nd table.